Why can I open site on tablet, but not computer?
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on my computer and some version of Android on my tablet. Both my computer and my tablet are on the same network. When I try to access archive.org on my tablet, I succeed without problem. When, at the same time, I try on my computer, I'm told the site's taking too long to respond.
Are there some things I can check in an attempt to find out why my computer's not connecting, but my tablet is?

If other sites work it could be a problem on their end.  Does incognito work? Other browsers? Do you have a VPN?  Browser agent?

It can be some browser configuration problem, do you use any extensions? Does a newly created, fresh profile in your browser open the site? Do you use DNS over HTTPS on either your tablet or in your browser on Ubuntu, and are the settings for this option different?

How annoying (in one sense). Today, it's working. Thank you both for your suggestions. If (or probably when) the problem recurs, I'll definitely try to connect on my computer via Firefox instead of Chrome and see if that makes a difference. The other suggestions are beyond me. Thank you again.
